# Varnishncsa for Varnish 4 split log by Vhost

Tags: logging, virtualhost, varnish, regex, varnishncsa

In the varnish 3, varnishncsa can support -m option (-m tag:regex only list records where tag matches regex. Multiple -m options are AND-ed together. ). After upgraded to varnish 4, I cannot find the -m option in varnish 4. Is it any easy way to upgrade from 3 to 4. Please advice.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can split by different hosts using:

```
varnishncsa -q "ReqHeader ~ '^Host: .*\.example1.com'"
varnishncsa -q "ReqHeader ~ '^Host: .*\.example2.com'"
```